# Hive SELECT col, COUNT(*) mismatch

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Let me start by saying, I am very new to Hive, so I'm not sure what information folks will need to help me out. Please let me know what information would be useful. Also, while I'd usually create a small dataset to recreate the problem with, I think this problem has to do with the scale of my dataset, because I can't seem to recreate the problem on a smaller dataset. Let me know if you have suggestions to make this more easy to answer.

Okay now that's out of the way, here's my problem. I have a huge dataset, partitioned by month, with about 500 million rows per month. I have a column with an ID number in it (I'll call it idcol), and I want to closely examine a couple of examples where there's a high number of repeated IDs and a very low number. So, I used this:

```
SELECT idcol, COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE month = 7 GROUP BY idcol LIMIT 10;
```

And got:

```
000005185884381 13
000035323848000 24
000017027256315 531
000010121767109 54
000039844553332 3
000013731352481 309
000024387407996 3
000028461234451 67
000016564844672 1
000032933040806 17
```

So, I went to investigate the first idvar with a count of 3, with:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE month = 7 AND idcol = '000039844553332';
```

I expected to see just 3 rows, but ended up with 469 rows found! That was strange enough, but then I just happened to run the original line of code above but with `LIMIT 5` instead and ended up with:

```
000005185884381 13
000017027256315 75
000010121767109 25
000013731352481 59
000024387407996 1
```

And, it may be hard to see because the idcol is so long, but idvar `000017027256315` ended up with a count of 531 when I did `LIMIT 10` and just 75 when I did `LIMIT 5`.

What am I missing?! How can I get a correct count of just a small number of values so I can investigate further?!

BTW my first thought was to make the counting part a sub-query, but that didn't change a thing. I used:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT idcol, COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE month = 7 GROUP BY idcol) x LIMIT 10;
```

...same EXACT results

Comment: The notation COUNT(*) includes NULL values in the total.
The notation COUNT(column_name) only considers rows where the column contains a non-NULL value.

Can you give the below code a try and let us know 
`SELECT idcol, COUNT(idcol) FROM table WHERE month = 7 GROUP BY idcol LIMIT 10;`

Comment: @Joby tried it -- no luck. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the counts are being computed from statistics.See here for the [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11266) and the related discussion.

```
hive.compute.query.using.stats = FALSE
```

If this doesn't fix it try the ANALYZE  command before running the count(*)

```
ANALYZE TABLE table_name PARTITION(month) COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```

Comment: It does seem to *change* the results but they're still not correct or consistent. I also logged out and logged back in in the meantime, so unsure if this actually caused the change...? This has me so befuddled!